# Voltage and current spacetime propagation in a circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, maxwell-equations, causality

It is often stated that for lumped circuits the signal propagation can be considered instantaneous, so the the circuit parameters do not depend on space coordinates.

**But how to actually derive this fact from Maxwell's equations?**

First I would like to know how to derive the general space-dependent voltage and current expression in a circuit. Then the lumped case can be obtained by letting the space dimensions go to $0$.

*Edit: I have seen [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/102458/%E2%80%A6). The problem is that there is no "small-sized" circuit $d << \lambda$ assumption made anywhere in the derivation. **I cannot even see, why that derivation cannot apply to large circuits and I want the answer to this question to explain this as well.** Also, I wanted to see how to go about deriving the distributed circuit equation first, and then using the approximation, instead of using the approximation along the way - and let alone using it somehow implicitly, unrigorously, without even writing it down, as was in the answer I linked*.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/102458/how-can-kvl-kcl-be-derived-from-maxwell-equations?rq=1?

Comment: I made an edit and explained why it is not

Comment: Just because the answer there does not use the specific condition $d \ll \lambda$ does not mean that it didn't answer that part. The part about discretisation is the relevant part, and can be translated into the lumped circuit case.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I don't see how to translate this. In the answer the discretization was actually mentioned only after the laws were derived.

Comment: That is because Maxwell's equations are the correct equations; its classical use is valid until quantum corrections are needed. So the form of the equations in deriving the lumped circuit approximations do not come with the lumped circuit limitations. It is only when you take the discretisation step do you insert the lumped circuit simplifications.

Comment: There is no assumption of "small circuits" in the lumped circuit model. If you want to have a large circuit in which stray inductances, stray capacitances and delay matter, then you simply insert those elements into your lumped circuit yourself. How granular a lumped circuit is and in which frequency range it stops being a good model is your responsibility. Typically we are simulating electronics well into the GHz range with lumped circuit models. It doesn't really break down until 3d modes become excited. That's the only thing it can't handle.

Comment: @FlatterMann "small circuits" means $d << \lambda$

Comment: I have done plenty of simulations of long delay lines l>>lambda with lumped circuits. It's absolutely no problem and totally not forbidden by lumped circuit theory. What is true is that "a wire" in a lumped circuit does not model "a physical wire". That's why we are talking about "nodes" in the theory and not wires. Those only exist in our schematic design entry tools as a graphical convenience for us.

Comment: On a more general note, if you wanted to understand the physics of the lumped circuit approximation better, then you should probably look into the "opposite end" of the problem: the plane wave approximation in optics. My best guess would be that they are highly related, if not even equivalent, but I will let a theoretical physicist take that one on. To me its only a hunch and I might be overlooking something.